# How to write just one query to divide result from 2 query?

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a query in Entity Framework Core like below:

```
var currencyRate = await AsyncExecuter.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
                    from exchangeRate in await _exchangeRateRepository.GetQueryableAsync()
                    where exchangeRate.CurrencyId == input.SelectedCurrencyId &&
                          exchangeRate.FirmId == input.FirmId &&
                          (exchangeRate.BeginDate <= input.ProcessDate && exchangeRate.EndDate >= input.ProcessDate)
                    select exchangeRate.CurrencyRate);

currencyRate = currencyRate / (await AsyncExecuter.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
                    from exchangeRate in await _exchangeRateRepository.GetQueryableAsync()
                    where exchangeRate.CurrencyId == input.CurrencyId &&
                          exchangeRate.FirmId == input.FirmId &&
                          (exchangeRate.BeginDate <= input.ProcessDate && exchangeRate.EndDate >= input.ProcessDate)
                    select exchangeRate.CurrencyRate));
```

I am dividing one currencyRate to another from 2 queries. There are 2 select queries. Only difference between queries is where condition. How to do this in one select query?

Comment: Is there an order by? or is there only one database row?

Comment: No, There is not order by. For every query there is only database row

Comment: Then surely you can get both rows with `where (exchangeRate.CurrencyId == input.CurrencyId || exchangeRate.CurrencyId == input.SelectedCurrencyId) .... .ToListAsync()`.

Comment: Use an or `||`, select the currency ID too so you can tell which is which, and sort the two rows out on the client.. or use the CurrencyId/SelectedCurrencyId to force the ordering so you know which is row 1 and which is row 2

Comment: @JeremyLakeman but how do I decide which one to divide into which from list?

Comment: By selecting and then locating each Id value again. Or you can swap `select ... .ToListAsync()` with `.ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.CurrencyId, x => x.CurrentcyRate)` to simplify locating each value.

Comment: How many rows ar ein the database table?

Comment: @CaiusJard 20-30 approximately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull both rows with

```
where (exchangeRate.CurrencyId == input.CurrencyId || exchangeRate.CurrencyId == input.SelectedCurrencyId)
```

Put an explicit order by on like

```
order by exchangeRate.CurrencyId == input.CurrencyId ? 0 : 1
```

Now you know the two rows you get back are in (currencyid, selectedcurrencyid) order so you can eg ToArray them and do `array[1] / array[0]`